# Can't use software 'rosetta' rough set tool on windows 10

Tags: windows, machine-learning, windows-10

I just downloaded and tried to install the 'Rosetta' rough sets tool on my laptop with OS Windows 10, but I can't. And after I search, it seems only compatible for Windows 98 / XP. But the problem I saw in the video tutorial is that anyone can run it on an OS that looks like that. Does anyone know of a solution to being able to use Rosetta on Windows 10?

[Error message when I install Rosetta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzybm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this problem after many days of googling and trying various ways. I use the "**Run programs made for previous versions of Windows**" feature in the control panel, then troubleshoot. I have also written down the step I did on that, and I uploaded in my medium story, but in "Bahasa Indonesia". So if you want to read it, you can translate it into English first to understand.

The medium link below:
https://medium.com/@andini.pratiwi/tidak-bisa-install-software-old-version-karena-tidak-compatible-dengan-os-windows-10-solusinya-1d8820c71572